# How to convert from the raw coding system to latin-1

Tags: emacs, encoding

I am having a file which used to be encoded in Latin-1.  Now, when I open this file, I get the raw-encoding only. That is `-t:` in the status line. There are probably some non Latin-1 characters in the file, at least opening other Latin-1 files works.

I would like to change the file back to Latin-1 only.  So I <kbd>C-x RETURN f</kbd> the buffer to `latin-1`.  However, upon saving, I get as non-encodable characters `\344` which is ä, `\374` which is ü and so on.  So the characters are actually here but are for some reason still misinterpreted.

---

By rote search, I found a `\237` to be the culprit. What is odd is that that character is not identified as non Latin-1 upon saving, but causes the file to be no longer recognized as Latin-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to find out what encoding the file is now in. Then, <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>`the file's encoding`<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`file` (i.e. open the file using its encoding). Then you can save it using latin-1.

Comment: That is great: I now can see all the characters as ä and not `\344`, **however**, upon reading the file next time (without the C-x Return c prefix), I am back to the original state. I made some tiny modifications but this did not help me either.

Comment: @false: What kind of file it is? There are ways how to tell emacs what encoding it should use, but they depend on the type of the file.

Comment: it is a regular Latin-1 text file I am editing.  See my edit to my question for the reason behind - what is so odd is that the culprit character is not displayed upon saving. But this seems to be an emacs problem. So thank you a lot!